# How can I make this Asp.net button have the same CSS as this <button>?

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm new to Asp.net webforms, and still learning CSS.  I am making a website which uses an html template I bought.

My problem is that the template makes use of  tags, but I need to use Asp.net button controls.  I tried to take the  css classes and put them in my button control's CSSClass property, but it's not displaying right.

You can view an example here: [link removed since page is being taken down]

The green "Send Password" button is the  and I want the other "Send Password" button (which is the .net control) to be styled the same way.

I've looked around and only find answers relating to overwriting how  tags are rendered which I don't want to do right now.  Is there an easy way to just make it look the same with CSS?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can hardly see the green password button. You really want it to be styled that way?

Comment: @mason Yes because it's just a test page, that's not what I'd actually use in deployment. I mostly just want to know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from `btn btn-default btn-clean` to `btn btn-success btn-clean` in your `asp:Button` markup declaration. Either in the `CssClass` or `css` attribute.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that! I applied that change, however the button is still much wider, filling up the div that's it's in where as the button I'm copying stays tighter to the text.  Any idea what I need to change to have that effect?

Comment: @Cineno28 That's probably due to the div wrappers around it. If you reverse the order of the buttons, I bet the buttons would swap positions and sizes. So you probably should change the divs. I noticed one of them has a modal class applied, though it's clearly not a modal popup.

Comment: I saw that the template stylesheet had a property for input types that made the width 100% and since it wasn't rendering as a <button> that's what it picked up.  I took that out and now it's looking just like the <button> CSS.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The green style is applied by the `.btn-success` class:

```
.btn.btn-success.btn-clean {
    border-color: #59AD2F;
    background: transparent;
    color: #59AD2F;
}
```

But your ASP.NET button is using the `.btn-default` class. Set it to `.btn-success` (probably in the `CssClass=""` property)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about this is to just copy and paste the css from your purchased template into the Site.css file for your WebForms application.

For example, copy (from @LcSalazar's answer)...

```
.btn.btn-success.btn-clean {
    border-color: #59AD2F;
    background: transparent;
    color: #59AD2F;
}
```

... into Site.css. `btn btn-success btn-clean` should appear as an option in the button properties CssClass drop down list.

Not the cleanest way to accomplish what you want, but definitely the fastest while still using the properties view. More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398932(v=vs.110).aspx), starting with the "Creating and Using a Stylesheet" if you're interested in creating a tidier solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in other button(white one) the same class as the green button which is `.btn btn-success btn-clean`:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSendPasswordNew" value="Send Password" id="btnSendPasswordNew" class="btn btn-success btn-clean">
```